# AspNet Core 3.1: error cast IdentityUser to ApplicationUser

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In asp net core mvc 3.1 i get an error when try to cast IdentityUser to ApplicationUser

I have created the following class to customize the user:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public String NotificationEmail { get; set; }
}
```

After the migration, in the table AspNetUsers i see the NotificationEmail Field.

Now i have create a controller/Action

```
public class UserSettingsController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UserSettingsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
   {
       var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
       ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

       return View(currentUser );
   }
```

The problem is that the compiler, in this instruction:

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

tell me that it's impossible to cast the type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser to ApplicationUser.

How can i get the current ApplicationUser in order to modify the custom field NotificationEmail in the view?

Comment: `FindByIdAsync` returns `IdentityUser` and you can not set a parent refrence to child but it can be done vice versa. If you registered `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` you should use the same for injecting.

Answer (score 2):

use
`UserMnager<ApplicationUser>` Insted of `UserManager<IdentityUser>`